# Laravel - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'posts_user_id_unique

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8

**I have an error**:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'posts_user_id_unique'

If I create post and using the same user, the error will appear

and if you use a different user, it will works.

this my code in migration, **create_posts_table.php**:

```
$table->id();
$table->foreignId('user_id')->unique()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
```

**create_categories_tables.php:**

```
$table->id();
$table->string('name')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
```

and this is my code in controller, **PostController:**

```
public function create(){
        $this->authorize('create', Post::class);
        $categories = Category::pluck('name','id');
        return view ('admin.posts.create', ['categories'=>$categories]);
    }
public function store(){
        $this->authorize('create', Post::class);
        $inputs = request()->validate([
            'title'=>'required',
            'post_image'=>'file', //mime: jpeg, png
            'body'=>'required',
            'category_id'=> 'required'
        ]);
        if(request('post_image')){
            $inputs['post_image'] = request('post_image')->store('images');
        }
        auth()->user()->posts()->create($inputs);
        session()->flash('post-create-message', 'Post was Created ' . $inputs['title']);
        // return back();
        return redirect()->route('post.index');
```

Comment: Remove ``unique()`` from ``$table->foreignId('user_id')->unique()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');`` and run your migration again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should remove

```
->unique()
```

in

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->unique()->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
```

If NOT, user will get the above error when creating 2nd post

Comment: thanks you, it works.. i forgot that i was using `unique()`...